# Rotate a UIKit element without messing up the frame

Tags: ios, rotation, slider, uikit

I have a need for rotating UISlider via its superclass property transform, by changing the rotation matrix with:

```
self.slider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(45);
```

In the documentation for UIView I can see a warning saying:

> Warning If this property is not the identity transform, the value of
>   the frame property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

So, the question is, how can I rotate a standard UIKit element without messing up frame rect? (By undefined I understand, they mean, totally messed up, not just enlarged enough to contain entire rotated object)

Comment: Why is messing up the frame rectangle important for you?  What are you using it for, after your rotation?  By the way, [CGAffineTransformMakeRotation takes radians, not degrees](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: I was worrying it might have an effect on behavior of the element and that I may run into some problems with proper placement/replacement of that element on the screen later on.

Comment: Are you specifically performing manual layout on this slider later by setting `self.slider.frame = newFrame;`?  If you've added a rotation transform, for example, and later need to translate or scale the slider, you should just add those new transforms to the existing rotation.  Transform matrices can be combinations of several different operations.

Comment: That I know, the question is what does "undefined" mean in that context, something like uninitialized variable in C - god knows whats there? Or does it mean, frame gets enlarged for example if the view gets rotated, and I can still use that frame value in a meaningful some way.

Comment: *Undefined* means you cannot reliably use that `frame` value in any meaningful way.

Comment: That warning in docs was always strange to me. Frame always worked as expected when used with non-identity transforms (as a bounding box). Even setting frame worked without a single bug. That means I ignore this warning in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you set the transform on a view, you will want to set its size and position by using the bounds and center properties. When setting the frame on a view, UIKit will actually set the bounds/center/transform on your view.

So without setting a transform you can set the frame like this.

```
self.slider.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 50);
```

When using a transform, you would have to do it like this:

```
self.slider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(45);
self.slider.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50);
self.slider.center = CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 50);
```